# why does my jump animation stops in middle and return to idle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i think i m making a mistake in controlling the animation transition and their parameters.. i m a complete beginner to unity.. can someone help me on it pls.. the jump animation keeps quitting in middle and return to idle without being completed..
Transition are

Idle to run ; isRunning = true

Run to idle ; isRunning = false

Run to jump ; isJumping = true

idle to jump ; isjumping = true

jump to idle ; isjumpinh = false

i have tried doing several things but it didnt work out.. if this is a beginner problem i m sorry but i cant get it to work

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
  {
   private Animator anim;
    private Rigidbody rb;

float runningSpeed = 30f;
float jumpForce = 20f;
bool isJumping = false;
bool isRunning = false;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    anim = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    move();
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        jump();
    }
    animate();

}

void move()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.Translate(runningSpeed * Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
         isRunning = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}

void jump()
{
    rb.AddForce(jumpForce * Vector3.up , ForceMode.Impulse);
    isJumping = true;
}

void animate()
{
    anim.SetBool("isRunning",isRunning);
    anim.SetBool("isJumping", isJumping);
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.transform.name == "Ground" && isJumping)
        isJumping = false;
}


}
```

Comment: why you are calling `anim.SetBool` on each frame? call it whenever it is necessary.

Comment: If you are starting to use Unity I suggest you to follow this man's tutorial, he also teaches good practises and it's easy to understand. In this video he does what you want he has many other tutorials (this video is for Unity2D but it can help you with 3D too) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA

Comment: ok thanks i will try.. i m just learning the concepts now so thanks for helping..

Comment: You shouldn't use transform.Translate, you will have some collision issues. Move your character with the rigidbody instead

Comment: You can use properties to control the flow of your bool values to the animator with getters and setters. I would not send bool values every frame: only on change.